# How can I parse the left associative notation of SKI combinator calculus

Tags: haskell

I've tried a bunch of stuff, and they always seem to result in one of 2 things:

- Program hangs forever (infinite left recursion)
- Right associativity (right recursion)

My only idea now is just to parse from the end of the string instead of the beginning, but do to the list nature of haskell's strings, that would require either traversing the list for every charachter, or parsing a reversed string. Neither option sound good.

Here's the relevant bits from my current code (which is right associative). I've tried left recursion, but it just ends up in an infinite loop.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternGuards #-}

data C = S | K | I deriving (Read,Show,Eq)
data T = N T T | C C deriving Eq

parse :: String -> T
parse s | (e,rest) <- parseStep s = if rest == "" then e else N e (parse rest)

parseStep :: String -> (T,String)
parseStep ('(':s) = parseParen s 
parseStep (c:s) = (C $ read [c],s)

parseParen (c:')':s) = (C $ read [c],s)
parseParen s = parseStep s
```

Comment: Where you now parse `T`s, you could instead parse `[T]`s, indicating a left-associative chain of applications, and then at opportune moments use `foldl` to turn the list back into a `T`.

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out thanks to luqui's comment:

```hs
parse :: String -> T
parse = foldTs . parseList

foldTs :: [T] -> T
foldTs (t:ts) = foldl N t ts

parseList :: String -> [T]
parseList "" = []
parseList s = let (x,r) = parseStep s in x:parseList r

parseStep :: String -> (T,String)
parseStep ('(':s) = let (ts,r) = parseParenList s in (foldTs ts,r)
parseStep (c:s) = (C $ read [c],s)


parseParenList :: String -> ([T],String)
parseParenList (')':s) = ([],s)
parseParenList s =
  let
    (x,r) = parseStep s
    (xs,r') = parseParenList r
  in (x:xs,r')
```

Comment: Good job! This looks like what luqui was suggesting, and it's also how I'd be likely to approach this problem.

Comment: Incidentally, this is the standard solution for getting rid of left recursion. You can always replace a left-recursive production like `A -> A B | C` with a wrapper around a right-recursive production `A -> C X` & `X -> B X | ε` (`ε` = empty string), or with iteration `A -> C B*` (`*` = Kleene star = `many`). Note that some other parsing tools like Happy can actually parse in either direction, but have better performance with *left* recursion, taking linear stack space for right recursion.